# truffle migrate ran out of gas

Tags: solidity, javascript, truffle-migration

I'm trying to migrate my contract to a mainnet fork using ganache-cli:

`ganache-cli -f https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{infuraKey} -l 8000000000000 --defaultBalanceEther 1000000000 --allowUnlimitedContractSize`

Using these configurations:

```
 development: {
  network_id: '*',
  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
  port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
  gas: 8000000000000, 
},
```

Whenever I run `truffle migrate`, I get this error:

```
2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Deploying '{contractName}'
   ------------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"{contractName}" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)
   * Block limit:  8000000000000 (0x746a5288000)
   * Gas sent:     8000000000000 (0x746a5288000)
```

As you can see, I've increased the block limit and gas limit to an extremely high amount and I'm still running out of gas, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

My contract was over 24kb, reduced contract size and that fixed it.